# Delete from table where file paths do not share roots

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to delete files that are not apart of 2 or more `collections`. My current query is deleting everything. I am trying to delete everything in `C:/Users/untun/Documents/other` but it is also deleting `C:/Users/untun/Documents` as well.

```sql
DELETE FROM files WHERE files.path in (
  SELECT files.path FROM files LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT json_extract(info, '$.path') AS path FROM collections
    WHERE json_extract(info, '$.path') LIKE 'C:/Users/untun/Documents/other_%'
  ) AS c ON files.path LIKE c.path || '%'
  WHERE c.path IS NULL
)
```

This is how the two tables are laid out:

```
collections

| info                                      |
|-------------------------------------------|
| {"path":"C:/Users/untun/Downloads"}       |
| {"path":"C:/Users/untun/Documents"}       |
| {"path":"C:/Users/untun/Documents/other"} |
```

```
files

| path                                      |
|-------------------------------------------|
| C:/Users/untun/Documents/cat.txt          |
| C:/Users/untun/Documents/other/dog.txt    |
| C:/Users/untun/Downloads/123.txt          |
```

- If I delete the `C:/Users/untun/Documents` collection everything will be delete except for anything in `C:/Users/untun/Documents/other` and `C:/Users/untun/Downloads`.
- If I delete the `C:/Users/untun/Documents/other` collection nothing will be deleted because the files are also in `C:/Users/untun/Documents`.
- If I delete the `C:/Users/untun/Downloads` folder everything in that folder will be delete but the other two folders will be left alone.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the `LEFT JOIN` as this will always include all path from files.

An `INNER JOIN` like in the following example will only select rows, that have the same path.

```
DELETE FROM files WHERE files.path in (
  SELECT files.path FROM files INNER JOIN (
    SELECT json_extract(info, '$.path') AS path FROM collections
    WHERE json_extract(info, '$.path') LIKE 'C:/Users/untun/Documents/other_%'
  ) AS c ON files.path LIKE c.path || '%'
  WHERE c.path IS NULL
)
```

Comment: Running this select finds no results for `C:/Users/untun/Documents/other_%`, which is correct, but running it on `C:/Users/untun/Documents_%` also gives no results.

Comment: this is correct as the sample has no such rows. a underline is a character which mus be in the path name